# How to specify null value to Powershell -AddParameter

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to issue a Powershell command in C# for changing the Microsoft Exchange Retention Policy, like:

```
Powershell ps = Powershell.Create();
ps.AddCommand("Set-Mailbox);
ps.AddParameter("-Identity", Identity);
ps.AddParameter("-RetentionPolicy", PolicyName);
...etc...
```

This works great if I have a PolicyName like "Company Default Policy".  Everything works as expected.

But, to remove a policy, the command line Powershell command looks like:

```
PS> Set-Mailbox -Identity TypicalUser -RetentionPolicy $null
```

If I try to pass "$null" and do this:

```
ps.AddParameter("-RetentionPolicy", "$null");
```

...then Powershell gives me an error that "$null is not a valid name of a retention policy".

I also tried:

```
ps.AddParameter("-RetentionPolicy", null);
```

...and this confused Powershell as there wasn't a value.

Am I missing something obvious in how to speak to Powershell right ?

Comment: What if you don't add the parameter at all?

Comment: Which version of Powershell ?

Comment: Version of Powershell is 2.0

Comment: If I don't add the parameter, then I get an error indicating that Powershell thinks I am passing "true" to the command.  No parameter must default to 'true'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `-` in the name in C# e.g.:

```
ps.AddParameter("RetentionPolicy", null);
```

Comment: Now that is wierd.  I can set a policy with the -RetentionPolicy followed by a non-null policy, but if I want to pass a null I have to put the parameter without the dash, and then pass a null.  Thank you.

For the record, this (Powershell) is a real flaky language...

Comment: @missioncritical Remember that in C# you are dealing with the PowerShell engine API.  With the API there is no need to use `-` to delineate between parameter names and values.

Comment: Thanks again, I would have never figured this out, as all of our other routines have the -parametername, value, but then we always have a text value or true/false, but never needed a null until now.